# How can I subscribe to incoming SSE events using Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, server-sent-events

I wrote a Spring `RestController` that returns a `SseEmitter` (for server-sent-event), and adds HATEOAS links to each event. Here is a simplified but working example of this controller:

```
package hello;

import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn;
import hello.Greeting.Status;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetingController.class);

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

    class GreetingRequestHandler implements Runnable {

        private ResponseBodyEmitter emitter;
        private Greeting greeting;

        public GreetingRequestHandler(final ResponseBodyEmitter emitter, final Greeting greeting) {
            this.emitter = emitter;
            this.greeting = greeting;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                log.info(this.greeting.toString());
                this.emitter.send(this.greeting);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                if (Status.COMPLETE.equals(this.greeting.getStatus())) {
                    this.emitter.complete();
                } else {
                    this.greeting.incrementStatus();
                    new Thread(new GreetingRequestHandler(this.emitter, this.greeting)).start();
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/greeting")
    public SseEmitter greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") final String name) {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        Greeting greeting = new Greeting(String.format(template, name));
        greeting.add(linkTo(methodOn(GreetingController.class).greeting(name)).withSelfRel());
        new Thread(new GreetingRequestHandler(emitter, greeting)).start();
        log.info("returning emitter");
        return emitter;
    }
}
```

The `Greeting` class is the following:

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Greeting extends ResourceSupport {

    private final String content;
    private final static AtomicInteger idProvider = new AtomicInteger();
    private int greetingId;
    private Status status;

    enum Status {
        ENQUEUED,
        PROCESSING,
        COMPLETE;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Greeting(@JsonProperty("content") final String content) {
        this.greetingId = idProvider.addAndGet(1);
        this.status = Status.ENQUEUED;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    protected void setStatus(final Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getGreetingId() {
        return this.greetingId;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Greeting{id='" + this.greetingId + "', status='" + this.status + "' content='" + this.content + "', " + super.toString() + "}";
    }

    public void incrementStatus() {
        switch (this.status) {
            case ENQUEUED:
                this.status = Status.PROCESSING;
                break;
            case PROCESSING:
                this.status = Status.COMPLETE;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly. If I try to reach the REST service using a web browser, I see events appearing with correct content and link.

The result looks like (each event appearing 5 seconds after the previous one):

```
data:{"content":"Hello, Kraal!","greetingId":8,"status":"ENQUEUED","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=Kraal"}}}
data:{"content":"Hello, Kraal!","greetingId":8,"status":"PROCESSING","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=Kraal"}}}
data:{"content":"Hello, Kraal!","greetingId":8,"status":"COMPLETE","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=Kraal"}}}
```

Now I need to call this REST service and read these events from another Spring application... But I have no clue how to write the client code using Spring. This does not work as `RestTemplate` is designed for synchronous client side HTTP access...

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());

    // required for HATEOAS
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/hal+json"));
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

    // required in order to be able to read serialized objects
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter2 = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter2.setSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/octet-stream"));
    converter2.setObjectMapper(mapper);

    // required to understand SSE events
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter3 = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter3.setSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.parseMediaTypes("text/event-stream"));

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    converters.add(converter);
    converters.add(converter2);
    converters.add(converter3);

    // probably wrong template
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(converters);
    // this does not work as I receive events and no a single object
    Greeting greeting = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/greeting/?name=Kraal", Greeting.class);
    log.info(greeting.toString());
```

The error message I get is:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'data': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

Indeed each event is a SSE event and starts with "data:"...

**So the questions are**:

- what ObjectMapper module should I register in order to be able to map SSE with Jackson ?
- how can I subscribe to incoming SSE events (observer pattern) using Spring ?

Thanks in advance.

**Side note**: As I'm struggling doing it using Spring I tried to do it using Jersey SSE support as follows. Using Jersey I receive events as expected, but then I can't cast them to a `Greeting` class (for the same reason as above I guess which is that I don't have the right converter module .):

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(converter).register(SseFeature.class).build();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/greeting/?name=Kraal");
EventInput eventInput = target.request().get(EventInput.class);
while (!eventInput.isClosed()) {
    final InboundEvent inboundEvent = eventInput.read();
    if (inboundEvent == null) {
        // connection has been closed
        break;
    }
    // this works fine and prints out events as they are incoming
    System.out.println(inboundEvent.readData(String.class));
    // but this doesn't as no proper way to deserialize the
    // class with HATEOAS links can be found
    // Greeting greeting = inboundEvent.readData(Greeting.class);
    // System.out.println(greeting.toString());
}
```

Comment: Server Sent Events in my view were designed for Server to browser communication. Your situation demands more of a server to server communication.

In my application, I used a pub sub message queue provided by Redis ( but you can use any other). The idea is any number of spring applications can publish to the queue and all the applications subscribing to it will receive the message.
See if this helps https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-redis/

Comment: I am using ResponseBodyEmitter to send data. Will this Jersey approach works for me?

Answer (score 0):

as per the [documentation](http://%20https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/sse/InboundEvent.html)

you can use `inboundEvent.readData(Class<T> type)`

Comment: doc link is broken

Comment: please use this https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/sse/InboundEvent.html